# How can I get a module from a URL and import it such that its problematic dependencies are ignored?

Tags: python, url, import, urllib

Ok, this is extremely hacky and silly programming. I have a function that can import a module file from a URL. It works fine and is hardly secure. I want to import a module file that has a problematic dependency (the system I'm on can't support that particular dependency) but the functionality I want from that module doesn't rely on the problematic dependency, so it's not a problem if it can be ignored.

My thinking is that I could use this `smuggle` function (shown below) to get the module file and then somehow import it using [FuckIt.py](https://github.com/ajalt/fuckitpy), but I'm not sure how to make these two ideas work together.

How could this be done?

```
import imp
import urllib

def smuggle(
    module_name = None,
    URL         = None
    ):
    if module_name is None:
        module_name = URL
    try:
        module = __import__(module_name)
        return(module)
    except:
        try:
            module_string = urllib.urlopen(URL).read()
            module = imp.new_module("module")
            exec module_string in module.__dict__
            return(module)
        except: 
            raise(
                Exception(
                    "module {module_name} import error".format(
                        module_name = module_name
                    )
                )
            )
            sys.exit()

damned_silly_module = smuggle(
    module_name = "damned_silly_module",
    URL = "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/https://github.com/justsomefuckingguy/damned_silly_module/master/damned_silly_module.py"
)

damned_silly_module.some_function_or_other()
```

Answer (score 1):

Putting aside `Fuckit.py`, if this is about a particular module with particular failing dependencies, the best way to get this to work is by making the import of the dependency succeed: Provide a mock sub-module with the same name, with stubs for whatever will be asked for. For example, if `damn_silly_module` tries to import `silly_walks`, which you don't have, make a mock `silly_walks` module and arrange for it to be found.

```
import sys
sys.path.insert(0, "path/to/mock/modules")
module = imp.new_module("module")
```

Or something like that. You could even catch `ImportError` and do this only if the module in question is absent. This is analogous to the python 2 custom of importing, say, `cPickle as pickle` and failing back to `import pickle` if that is unavailable.

If you want this to work in general, with modules you'll see in the future, you'd need to catch `ImportError`, examine it to figure out what's missing, mock it on the fly and try again.

Incidentally, your exception handling needs some work. Never catch *everything* (with `except:` with no arguments); catch `ImportError` (and perhaps `NameError` if the import succeeds but a later name lookup fails). Never raise an undifferentiated `Exception`, raise `ImportError`. In this case, it may be better to re-raise the exception you just caught, with a simple

```
raise
```

And get rid of `sys.exit()`. It's dead code-- it'll never be reached. (Also: `raise` is a keyword, you don't need function brackets around its arguments).

Comment: PS. Took a look at `fuckit`. Your best chance to make that work would be to save the downloaded module into a temporary file in your current directory (or elsewhere in your import path), so that you can use the `fuckit` API with it.